# log level in development and production asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, logging, .net-core

i am using asp.net core mvc and web api project

which has below version

```
 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

i'm also using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger to log some of information

for Example :  `_logger.LogInformation("special information log for xyz method");` for application insight.

so as per this post https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Dec/31/Dont-let-ASPNET-Core-Default-Console-Logging-Slow-your-App-down

i made log level like this in my local app setting project and hit play icon from visual studio and watching console logs in black window.

```
"LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
```

now when i do run of my application, still i'm able to see logs like this

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 35782.1232ms 200 text/html; charset=UTF-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:57526/polyfills.js
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:57526/styles.js
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:57526/vendor.js
```

Question #1 : why still i'm able to to see this log in console window where "info is from Microsoft" :(

Question #2 : what is your best recommendation(experiences) log level for production and development? i do not want to slow down my application due to wanted to log information logged to application insights.

program.cs

```
                    // Optional: Apply filters to control what logs are sent to Application Insights.
                    // The following configures LogLevel Information or above to be sent to
                    // Application Insights for all categories.
                    logging.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>
                                 ("", LogLevel.Information);

                }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 5):

> Question #1 : why still i'm able to to see this log in console window where "info is from Microsoft" :

Since you see the logging in development,you need to change log levels in `appsettings.Development.json` instead of `appsettings.json`, you could find the file just behind the `appsettings.json`.

[image]

> Question #2 : what is your best recommendation(experiences) log level for production and development? i do not want to slow down my application due to wanted to log information logged to application insights.

It is documented well, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#log-level

> In production:
>   Logging at the Trace through Information levels produces a high-volume of detailed log messages. To control costs and not exceed data storage limits, log Trace through Information level messages to a high-volume, low-cost data store.
>   Logging at Warning through Critical levels typically produces fewer, smaller log messages. Therefore, costs and storage limits usually aren't a concern, which results in greater flexibility of data store choice.
>
> During development:
>   Log Warning through Critical messages to the console.
>   Add Trace through Information messages when troubleshooting.

Comment: ```"LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }``` - is good for production? since i have _log.information("") written over code?

Comment: @Var IMO, there is no problem and you have to do that if you want to use the built in logger.Or you could log messages to an in-memory queue if you concern about the performance, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#no-asynchronous-logger-methods